# Switch Parameter overwrites a different parameter

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

While trying something out with powershell I found this interaction. When having a script with the following code:

```
param(
    [switch]$testSwitch = $false,
    [String[]]$names = "ABC","DEF")
echo "names: $names"
echo "test: $testSwitch"
```

And then calling it using:

```
.\testScript.ps1 -testSwitch true
```

The expected return for me would be that names is unchanged and that testSwitch returns True - as that is the default value for a switch independent from what the input actually is (My understanding at least).
The actual return is:

```
names: true
test: True
```

The value of testSwitch is not surprising to me, but that the value of names is overwritten by the value entered in testSwitch is. And I am struggling to understand why it does that.
So my question is, why does, while having named parameters, the value input for a certain parameter overwrite a completely different parameter?

And this only appears to be happening with switch, the same example with an int32 instead of a switch, and inputting 1 with a default parameter of 0, returns the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `-testSwitch` is a switch parameter, if you specify it without any value after it, then you are setting it to true.

Because you've used a string `true` as the value you are trying to set for it, instead of `$true`, its putting the string 'true' in to your other parameter.

Also, to send a specific value to a switch parameter, you specify it after a `:`. This will do what you expect:

```
.\testScript.ps1 -testSwitch:$true
```

Note this is only necessary for switch parameter values (but as previously stated, you don't have to specify a value typically because by just using it you're making it true).